# How to refresh the vuejs view via event?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to call a function to re-render the events after an event creation. The event is being fired but the view is not being updated.

I'm using Vue 2, vue-fullcalendar and Laravel 5.3.

I am successfully emitting the event, however the view is not being updated. If I add a button to the view and bind the method call to a click, it updates the view, refetching the events from my server. If I call it inside the component, it doesn't updates my browser view.

I am calling the `$emit` inside a `method` which is called inside a `mounted` component creation of vue-fullcalendar. I've created an `$on` to listen if the event is being triggered via my code. Everything seems to work fine, except the view automatic updating (which is the reason why I am using Vuejs).

Here's the complete code:

```
<template>
    <full-calendar  ref:"calendar" id="calendar" :event-sources="eventSources"></full-calendar >
</template>

<script>
require('fullcalendar')

export default {
    props: {
        events: {
            default() {
                return []
            }
        },
        eventSources: {
            default() {
                return [
                    {
                        events(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                            Vue.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getAgendamentosEventos', {timezone: timezone}).then(response => {
                                callback(response.data.events)
                            })
                        },
                        color: '#1ABC9C',
                    },
                    {
                        events(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                            Vue.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getDatasFechadas', {timezone: timezone}).then(response => {
                                callback(response.data.events)
                            })
                        },
                        color: '#DC0000',
                    }
                ]
            },
        },
        editable: {
            default() {
                return true
            },
        },
        selectable: {
            default() {
                return true
            },
        },
        selectHelper: {
            default() {
                return true
            },
        },
        header: {
            default() {
                return {
                    left:   'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right:  'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                }
            },
        },
        defaultView: {
            default() {
                return 'month'
            },
        },
        sync: {
            default() {
                return false
            }
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        const cal = $(this.$el),
            self = this;

        cal.fullCalendar({
            header: this.header,
            defaultView: this.defaultView,
            editable: this.editable,
            selectable: this.selectable,
            selectHelper: this.selectHelper,
            aspectRatio: 2,
            slotDuration: '00:10:00',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            events: self.events,
            eventSources: self.eventSources,
            fixedWeekCount: false,
            eventRender(event, element) {
                if (this.sync) {
                    self.events = cal.fullCalendar('clientEvents')
                }
            },
            eventDestroy(event) {
                if (this.sync) {
                    self.events = cal.fullCalendar('clientEvents')
                }
            },
            eventClick(event) {
                $(self.$el).trigger('event-selected', event);
                console.log('click');
                console.log(event);
                cal.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            },
            eventDrop(event) {
                console.log('drop-event');
                $(self.$el).trigger('event-drop', event);
            },
            eventResize(event) {
                $(self.$el).trigger('event-resize', event)
            },
            select(start, end, jsEvent) {
                var data = start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                var dia = start.format("dddd");

                $.fancybox({
                        type: "iframe",
                        href: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/agendamentos/create",
                        width: "80%",
                        height: "90%",
                        afterLoad: function() {
                            $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("input[name='dia_semana']").val(dia);
                            $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("select[name='profissionais[]']").attr("disabled","disabled");
                            $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("input[name='data']").val(data);
                            $(".fancybox-iframe").contents().find("input[name='data']").attr("readonly","readonly");
                        },
                        afterClose: function(){
                            console.log('afterclose');

                            setTimeout(function(){ console.log('primeiro'); self.refreshEvents(); }, 5000);

                            $(self.$el).trigger('event-created', {
                                start,
                                end,
                                allDay: !start.hasTime() && !end.hasTime(),
                            });

                            console.log('fim');
                        }
                });                    
            },
        });

        self.$on('refetch-events', function(){
            console.log('Event from parent component emitted');
        });

        self.$on('reload-events', function(){
            $(this.$el).fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
            console.log('rerender-events');
        });
    },
    methods: {
        refreshEvents() {
            console.log('chamou');
            this.$emit('refetch-events');
            this.$emit('rerender-events');
            this.$emit('reload-events');
        },
    },
    watch: {
        events: {
            deep: true,
            handler(val) {
                const cal = $(this.$el);
                cal.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                cal.fullCalendar('addEventSource', this.events);
                cal.fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
                cal.fullCalendar('refetch-events');
            },
        }
    },
    events: {
        'remove-event'(event) {
            $(this.$el).fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id)
        },
        'rerender-events'(event) {
            $(this.$el).fullCalendar('rerenderEvents')
        },
        'render-event'(event) {
            $(this.$el).fullCalendar('renderEvent', event)
        },
        'reload-events'() {
            $(this.$el).fullCalendar('removeEvents')
            $(this.$el).fullCalendar('addEventSource', this.events)
        },
        'rebuild-sources'() {
            $(this.$el).fullCalendar('removeEvents')
            this.eventSources.map(event => {
                $(this.$el).fullCalendar('addEventSource', event)
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

For reference:

[vue-fullcalendar](https://github.com/CroudSupport/vue-fullcalendar)

[vue-fullcalendar-example of event firing with button](https://github.com/BrockReece/vue-fullcalendar-example)

[github issue (partially solved, since the event is being fired just the view is not being updated automatically)](https://github.com/CroudSupport/vue-fullcalendar/issues/12)

I really don't know why it is (not) happening... any help is appreciated and also, this is a pretty usable reference for any developer using vue-fullcalendar live updates, so thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it `reload-events` that isn't caught?

Comment: So, the event should be refetch-events, which reloads the eventSources. The eventSources are http endpoints from which I get the events. The console.log messages are printed: **primeiro**, **chamou** and **Event from parent component emitted**, which means the event is being called. However the view is not updating. I've tried to get the other methods to maybe get it working, but it didn't.

Comment: Ok. It does look like there is a `this` issue with your `self.$on('reload-events',...)` though. I think it should be `$(self.$el).fullCalendar('rerenderEvents')`.

Comment: You must trigger the refetch event on calendar component
https://github.com/CroudSupport/vue-fullcalendar#listens-on